# Клиппировать векторную геометрию

Tags: oracle, spatial

Есть база данных на oracle, которая содержит несколько таблиц с пространственными данными.

Сам вопрос: каким образом можно получить геометрию (линии, полигоны) находящиеся внутри некоторого ограничивающего прямоугольника? Та геометрия, которая полностью внутри, возвращается целиком. Та геометрия, которая пересекает границу ограничивающего прямоугольника, должна обрезаться и возвращаться только кусок находящийся внутри.

Если из растра я могу вырезать прямоугольный кусок, то как быть с векторными данными, пока непонятно.

Comment: Можно вопрос примером тестовых данных дополнить?

Comment: Разобрался сам. Оказывается, всё легко делается через SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION.